# GAS : How to check if a file exists in a specific folder and if so go to the next iteration

Tags: google-sheets

I'm writing a script that does the following :

- send an email with an attachment (eg proof of payment) to people that register for our event when two criteria are met: payment has been processed, and if they have not yet received their proof of payment
- make a copy of an existing file, using some variables in the new copy (this works fine) to personalize the proof of payment.

The copy of the file gets a new name (personalized).
I seem to be unable to make the script check correctly if the file already exists or not.

Who can help me out ?

```js
function createDocument(e) {
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID', 'Lijst!A1:G');
  var lid = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID', 'Lijst!A2:G');
  var templateId = 'TEMPLATE ID';

  for (var j = 0; j < lid.values.length; j++) {

    if (lid.values[j][6] == 'ok' && lid.values[j][7] != 'Bewijs Verzonden') {

      //collect the data from the member
      var voornaam = lid.values[j][0];
      var familienaam = lid.values[j][1];
      var email = lid.values[j][2];
      var aantal = lid.values[j][3];
      var betaaldop = lid.values[j][5];


      //Make a copy of the template file
      var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
      var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
      var docname = 'Betalingsbewijs Reunie 2019 voor ' + familienaam + ' ' + voornaam + '.pdf';
      //var filecheck = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID');
      var filecheck = DriveApp.getFilesByName(docname);
      if (filecheck.hasNext()) {
        Logger.log("No File Found");
      } else {

        //Get the document body as a variable
        var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();


        //Insert the data from spreadsheet
        body.replaceText('<<Voornaam>>', voornaam)
        body.replaceText('<<Naam>>', familienaam)
        body.replaceText('<<Aantal deelnemers>>', aantal)
        body.replaceText('<<Betaald op>>', betaaldop)

        DocumentApp.openById(documentId).saveAndClose();

        //move file to new folder and remove from parent folder

        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
        file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
        DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID').addFile(file);

        var pdfname = file.setName('Betalingsbewijs Reunie 2019 voor ' + familienaam + ' ' + voornaam + '.pdf');
        var steil = "email@gmail.com";

        var blob = pdfname.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

        var subject = 'Betalingsbewijs Reunie 2019 voor ' + familienaam + ' ' + voornaam + ' met ' + aantal + 'deelnemer(s)';
        var htmlBody =
          "Beste " + voornaam + ", " +
          "<br/>" +
          "<br/>" +
          "<br/>Bedankt voor uw inschrijving voor de Steil reünie op zaterdag 26 januari 2019." +
          "<br/>Wij hebben uw betaling goed ontvangen." +
          "<br/>Uw deelname aan de reünie is nu definitief in orde." +
          "<br/>In bijlage kan u uw betalingsbewijs terugvinden in pdf." +
          "<br/><br/>Indien u nog vragen heeft kan u ons steeds bereiken via reunie.steil@gmail.com." +
          "<br/>Met verplegende groeten," +
          "<br/>Het Steil Reünie team";


        var optAdvancedArgs = {
          name: "Steil Reünie 2019",
          htmlBody: htmlBody,
          replyTo: email,
          cc: steil,
          attachments: [blob]
        };

        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, optAdvancedArgs);

        var ConfirmationRange = "Lijst!H" + [j + 2];
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ConfirmationRange).setValue('Bewijs Verzonden');

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. "I seem to be unable to make the script check correctly if the file already exists or not." Do you mean that your code is not successful, or that you don't know how to code for this? If its your code, have you added some Logger statements to test whether it is a problem with the folder, the file, the file name, etc In short, what have you done to identify where and why the problem exists?

Comment: Your function `createDocument(e)`... what trigger have you installed for this?

Comment: There are major flaws in your code. Did you copy it from somewhere? Please give the reference for where this code came from.